# Clustering WSO2 CEP 3.1.0 in full active-active mode with more than two members?

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, complex-event-processing

I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Complex+Event+Processor) to cluster WSO2 CEP 3.1.0 in high availability, full active-active mode and it works great when there are two members.

When I add a third member to the WKA group, all members acknowledge each other but now a duplicate event is emitted.

Is it possible to run the CEP in high availability mode with more than two members? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CEP 3.1.0 is only tested with two nodes, and we recommend you to use only two nodes for now. I have created a ticket to fix this in future releases. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-853

Suho